# How to Highlight a Component and Unhighlight Others in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a component named `<login-screen>`, and there are several instances of it on the page. All I want is to highlight the active button and un-highlight the other buttons. How can this be achieved in Vue.js?

Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<login-screen></login-screen>
<login-screen></login-screen>
<login-screen></login-screen>
```

The component template looks like this:

```
<button @click="highlight" class="selected:isSelected></button>
```

The highlight method as of this writing merely does a toggle:

```
highlight () {
   this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
}
```

The component has a `isSelected` property initialized to `false` like this:

```
data () {
   isSelected: false;
}
```

I just cannot get each component to be aware of the state of other components, since they are constraint to a local scope, nor can access the global properties in the same Vue instance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to set an id for each `<login-screen/>`  component so you can manage your selected component in the parent, and pass the `isSelected`  prop to the component.
But you also want to be able to change the selection from the inner button of the component, so you can `$emit` the change selection event like so:

The login-screen component:

```html
<button @click="$emit(‘change-selection’)" class="selected:isSelected></button>
```

```js
props: {
    isSelected: {
         type: Boolean,
         default: false
    }
}
```

The parent component:

```html
<login-screen
     is-selected=“selectedScreen === ‘screen-1’”
     @change-selection=“changeSelection(‘screen-1’)”
>
</login-screen>
```

Your script:

```js
data() {
   return: {
       selectedScreen: ‘screen-1’
   }
},
methods: {
    changeSelection(screen) {
         this.selectedScreen = screen
    } 
}
```

By the way instead of copy paste the `<login-screen>`  like above thee times with different id, I would recommend to use `v-for` on the `<login-screen>` component and loop over an array containing each screen id:

```html
<login-screen
     v-for=“screenId in screens”
     is-selected=“selectedScreen === screenId”
     @change-selection=“changeSelection(screenId)”
>
</login-screen>
```

```js
data() {
   return: {
       screens: [‘screen-1’, ‘screen-2’, ‘screen-3’]
   }
},
```

Comment: Executing the example you have outlined will not affect other components. When the event 'change-selection' is emitted and the test 'selectedScreen === screenId' pass, it will only highlight that component.

Comment: I wouldn't want to loop over this right now. Because <login-screen> can be followed by an uneven amount of other components or tags. The point is highlight and un-highlight all <login-screen> component, as I would with a class.

Comment: Can you give a working example of this? A link or a CodePen of some sort?

Comment: In response to your first comment, I guess I just didn’t understand your problem and thought it was you intention - to highlight only the component you selected. If you will better explain what you do I can help you find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution, and figured out there were no examples of this in one piece. This can be achieved with creating another instance of Vue or using Vuex. There could be other ways of doing this. Nevertheless, the accepted solution for managing states of components, directives, etc is via something like this:

https://njbenjamin.com/vuejs-vuex/Lesson15_Example12.htm

The state object to hold all the globally accessible properties is the following:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        count: 0,
        buttons: [],
        isSelected: false
    },
    mutations: {
        increment(state){
            state.count++;
        }
    }
});
```

Then comes the `highlight` method which is mapping all `<login-screen>` components state under the assumption 0 == not-selected and 1 == selected.

```
highlight () {
    const lIndex = (this.no - 1);
    store.state.buttons.map((button, gIndex) => {
        if(gIndex === lIndex)
            store.state.buttons[gIndex] = 1;
        else
            store.state.buttons[gIndex] = 0;
    });
    Vue.set(vm, 'buttons', function(){
        store.state.buttons[store.state.buttons.lenth - 1] = 1;
        this.buttons = store.state.buttons;
        return store.state.buttons;
    });
    console.log(store.state.buttons);
}
```

Comment: I think this is an over complicated solution, but if you want to use it I would recommend to read more about vuex store and best practices because you should not be changing state data from inside a component, you need to use mutations for this. Here is a link to the vuex documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: As simple as the idea of changing the state of a button sound, there's a reason it is not happening often i.e. it is complicated. I could go on and use a mutation to make sure the buttons array will be reactive, but that's also what happens inside the setter.

Comment: Don't get me wrong here, there's lots of room for improvements in this code. And will do so on some other project. I totally see why it is a good idea to create a mutation out of the highlight method period.

Comment: Also, bear in mind Vuex is recommended for medium to large scale applications. Its complexity will come in handy as your application grows.

Answer (score 0):

Using mutations, it would then become:

```
mutations: {
    highlight (state, obj) {
        const lIndex = (obj.no - 1);
        store.state.buttons.map((button, gIndex) => {
            if(gIndex === lIndex)
                store.state.buttons[gIndex] = 1;
            else
                store.state.buttons[gIndex] = 0;
        });
    }
}
```

Then inside the component would be like this:

```
methods: {
    highlight () {
        store.commit('highlight', {
            no: this.no
        });
        Vue.set(vm, 'buttons', function(){
            return store.state.buttons;
        });
        console.log(store.state.buttons);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a much simpler solution inspired by:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

**and**

https://njbenjamin.com/vuejs-vuex/Lesson15_Example16.htm

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <title>Changing The State of Buttons</title>
    <style>
          body{
              font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
              letter-spacing: 0.10rem;
              word-spacing: 0.25rem;
              color: black;
              background-color: #ccc;
          }
          #app{
              text-align: center;
          }
          button{
              border: 0.25rem solid black;
              background-color: black;
              padding: 0.75rem;
              border-radius: 0.25rem;
              cursor: pointer;
              margin: 0.75rem;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              color: white;
          }
          button.selected{
              background-color: white;
              border-color: white;
              color: black;
          }
    </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = app;
      function app(){
          let vm = new Vue({
              el: '#app',
              computed: {
                  count () {
                      return this.index;
                  }
              },
              data: {
                  buttons: 5, // Number of buttons
                  index: 0,
              },
              components: {
                  'login-screen' : {
                      props: ['no', 'index', 'buttons'],
                      template: `<button
                          :class="{selected: index === no}" 
                          @click="select(no)"
                      >button No. {{ no }}</button>`,
                      methods: {
                          select (no) {
                              vm.index = no;
                          }
                      }
                  }            
              }
          });

      };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <login-screen
            v-for="no in buttons" 
            class="login-screen"
            :key="no"
            :no="no"
            :buttons="buttons"
            :index="index"
        ></login-screen>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's :class=... so you need the : for the class/style to make it reactive.

I would add and remove the style form the active/non active object and let the others styled by the css styles.

Comment: It's using that in the component's template:
:class="{selected: index === no}" 
That last example is working, and I provided the full page and all dependencies, not sure why StackOverflow isn't rendering it.